# How can I get an Id from an existing Model Expression in AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm trying to build a view component in a Asp.Net Core 3.1 that takes a model expression as the model.

I have the following view for which the Model is a `ModelExpression`. How do I get an id the same way `@Html.IdFor(m => expr)` would?

```
@model Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression
<input id="*****" name="@Model.Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [aspnetcore source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/HtmlHelperOfT.cs#L235) shows:

```
        public string IdFor<TResult>(Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
        {
            if (expression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
            }

            return GenerateId(GetExpressionName(expression));
        }
```

Since `IdFor` actually generates the name and then converts to an id. One would can simply do `GenerateId` which is exposed via `Id`

```
@model Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression
<input id="@Html.Id(Model.Name)" name="@Model.Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
```